# Flex no-wrap pushing content out of other non-flex elements

Tags: css

I am lost on this one. I'm trying to set up a Javascript scroller where the content in the container needs to be inline, so it can be scrolled. If I use flex and `flex-wrap:nowrap`, it pushes the content out as it should, and I can scroll, but then the content in other areas of the form also follow suit by going out of their container. I only want the content in the flex container to overflow out of the element. How can I achieve this without bothering the rest of the content?

**Here is the code I'm using:**

```css
#scroll-years {
  width: 80%;
  max-width:75em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="scroll-years">
  <span><a href="#">2009</a></span>
  <span>&#8226;</span>
  <span><a href="#">2010</a></span>
  <span>&#8226;</span>
  <span><a href="#">2011</a></span>
  <span>&#8226;</span>
  <span><a href="#">2012</a></span>
  <span>&#8226;</span>
  <span><a href="#">2013</a></span>
  <span>&#8226;</span>
  <span><a href="#">2014</a></span>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
I just noticed that if I use `overflow:hidden` on the parent container of `#scroll-years`, everything looks good. I'm not an expert with CSS so I have to ask, can this be right?

**Edit**

```
#ap-container {
  max-width:75rem;
  width:95%;
  overflow:hidden; <-----Adding this pushes all the content back into place
}
```

Is this correct behavior or is this more of a hack? My objective is to learn how to code CSS better than I have been, so that's my concern.

Comment: Could you add the HTML code of the container and its internal elements with the relative CSS?

Comment: @TermoPollo, thanks for looking TermoPollo. I added the parent container, which is simply a div.

Comment: I'm going to have to post more code, this just isn't working right. I'll be back with more code.

Comment: Yes, that would be much better. If you post the whole code that pertains to the problem, I might be able to help you, for now it's a bit difficult for me to understand what you want, I could only make guesses.